# Onchange show data-attributes of select not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a selection element, with three options:

```
<select id="dimensions" onchange="showUpload(); setDimensions();">
    <option value="">Select dimension of the image</option>
    <option value="1" data-width="1600" data-height="1200">1600px x 1200px</option>
    <option value="2" data-width="600" data-height="400">600px x 400px</option>
</select>
```

Now, when I click an options it triggers 2 functions. The first one works perfectly, but the second one should alert me the data-attributes. But it doesn't.

Here's my function:

```
function setDimensions() {

    var width = $(this).attr("data-width");
    var height = $(this).attr("data-height");

    alert(width);


    $('#width').val($('#width').val() + width);
    $('#height').val($('#height').val() + height);

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

My showUpload function:

```
function showUpload() {

    $(".upload-image").show();

}
```

As an addon: It alerts: undefined.

Think if this shows an error, I should go back to primary school...

Comment: Please post "showUpload()" function

Comment: Does it alert anything at all? "undefined" perhaps?

Comment: Undefined indeed. Sorry, forgot to mention that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The this keyword refers to the window object. 
You could get the value directly from dimensions.

```
function setDimensions() {
   var dimensions = $("#dimensions");
   var selectedIndex = dimensions.get(0).selectedIndex;
   var selectedOption = dimensions.find("option").eq(selectedIndex);
   var width = selectedOption .attr("data-width");
   var height = selectedOption .attr("data-height");

   alert(width);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

within `setDimensions`, `this` would be your select element, and that doesn't have the "data-" attributes.

You can get the relevant option using `$('option:selected', this)`

The complete working function can be:

```
function setDimensions() {
    var option = $('option:selected', this);
    var width = option.attr("data-width");
    var height = option.attr("data-height");

//  Could also use: option.data('width')

    $('#width').val($('#width').val() + width);
    $('#height').val($('#height').val() + height);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**

See [Worked Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5anmhwq3/1/) for your example using jquery event **on(change)**  :

**HTML :**

```
<select id="dimensions">
    <option value="">Select dimension of the image</option>
    <option value="1" data-width="1600" data-height="1200">1600px x 1200px</option>
    <option value="2" data-width="600" data-height="400">600px x 400px</option>
</select>
```

**JS :**

```
$('#dimensions').on('change',function() {
    showUpload(); 
    setDimensions($(this));
});

setDimensions = function(_this) {  
    var width = $(_this).find(':selected').data("width");
    var height = $(_this).find(':selected').data("height");

    alert('width='+width+' & height='+ height);

    $('#width').val($('#width').val() + width);
    $('#height').val($('#height').val() + height);
}

showUpload = function() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If showUpload() function throws an error, then the second function will not be executed.